# Count number of occurrences before a certain point in a string

Tags: php, count, substr

I am looking to count the number of occurrences of "x" before a certain point in a string.

Eg. count all values that = x before the 5th character.

Any pointers on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by this `substr_count` yo can do:

```
substr_count($text, 'x', 0,5);
```

where `0` is `offset` where your start, and `5` is the `length`.

Comment: thanks very much for taking the time to help! much appreciated! i missed the part about offset when reading up on substr_count in the php manual! all makes sense now and works perfectly.